# How to compare just month and day from a datetime object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

In my C# program I have run into an obstacle where I have a table that stores date ranges (columns are date range ID (int), begin date (DateTime) and end date (DateTime). I want to query the table and get back rows that only fall within a specific date range. I cannot use datetime.date since that includes the year.

So for example, I want to query the table and get all date ranges that fall between 01-01 and 5-31.

I have tried using the following lambda to query the table, but my result set is empty.

```
List<DateRanges> tempDateRangeList = dataContext
                                     .DateRanges
                                     .Where(r=>r.BeginDate.Month <= startDate.Month 
                                               && r.EndDate.Month >= finishDate.Month)
                                     .ToList();

tempDateRangeList = tempDateRangeList.Where(r=>r.BeginDate.Day <= startDate.Day 
                                               && r.EndDate.Day >= finishDate.Day)
                                     .ToList();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Edit:

Examples of BeginDate and EndDate would be a list such as follows:

BeginDate 1/1/2016, 5/25/2016, 9/11/2016

EndDates 5/24/2016, 9/10/2016, 12/31/2016

Filter date would be:
startDate = 12/8
finishDate = 12/12

Expected result:
Begin Date of 9/11
End date of 12/31

Comment: so the above snippet is not working for you?

Comment: Yes, it isn't working. It gets all of the date ranges between the months (first line) but then it returns zero results when it tries to filter on the days (second line).

Comment: Can you give example dates for BegindDate and EndDate and also the filter dates and what exactly you want to have as result.

Comment: Yes, those were typos. This isn't the exact same code that I am working with; its merely an example.

Comment: Aren't all of your intervals backwards? Don't you want `Begin >= start && End <= finish`? You have the reverse, `Begin <= start && End >= finish`.

Comment: Have you tried to run this example code to see if works? It looks like it should. Then compare the working example to your real code to see where the differences are. Those differences will be where the error is. Also you don't really want to be storing the results of the first query as a concrete list.

Comment: Why are you separating those? can't you just compare dates: r.BeginDate <= startDate.Date && r.EndDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban the OP already said that they have to ignore the year part of the date.

Comment: Why is end date 12/31 included in the result if finish date is 12/12? Doesn't that make 12/31 be out of the filtered range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases in your condition - month equal to boundary month, in which case you must test day number, and a different month, in which you ignore day. Hence the query:

```
List<DateRanges> tempDateRangeList = 
    dataContext.DateRanges.Where(r =>
        ((r.BeginDate.Month < startDate.Month) || 
         (r.BeginDate.Month == startDate.Month && r.BeginDate.Day <= startDate.Day)) &&
        ((r.EndDate.Month > finishDate.Month) ||
         (r.EndDate.Month == finishDate.Month) && r.EndDate.Day >= finsihDate.Day))
    .ToList();
```

Condition is ugly and very hard to follow but covers all cases. This query returns all records which define date ranges that completely fall under the boundary dates.

If you wish to find records that are just overlapping (completely or partially) with the filtering range, then the query would be:

```
List<DateRanges> tempDateRangeList = 
    dataContext.DateRanges.Where(r =>
        ((r.BeginDate.Month < endDate.Month) || 
         (r.BeginDate.Month == endDate.Month && r.BeginDate.Day <= endDate.Day)) &&
        ((r.EndDate.Month > startDate.Month) ||
         (r.EndDate.Month == startDate.Month) && r.EndDate.Day >= startDate.Day))
    .ToList();
```

This condition may bend your mind, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a lambda expression isn't compulsory, I've used linq queries (because it was the first solution i've thought).

```
var validRanges = from range in ranges
                  where range.BeginDate.CompareTo(startDate) <= 0
                  where range.EndDate.CompareTo(endDate) >= 0
                  select range;
```

Using **CompareTo** is the easiest way to compare two DateTime struct.
I invite you to take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79949f0(v=vs.110).aspx) for a complete description of the method.

### Edit

If you aren't interested in hours of your dates, but only in Day and Month, you should use `range.BeginDate.Date.CompareTo(startDate.Date)` and `range.EndDate.Date.CompareTo(endDate.Date)`